# Configure VLAN on Cisco SG-200 switch connected to a Meraki switch/network

Tags: cisco, vlan, switchport, meraki

I have a Cisco SG-200-26 switch connected to a port on a Meraki switch.

The Meraki switch shows a list of all devices detected on that switch port (the Cisco switch and all of the devices connected to the Cisco switch).

I have VLANs configured on a Meraki L3 switch upstream from the Meraki switch.

The Meraki port is configured to be a ***Trunk port using native VLAN 10; allowed VLANs: all***

The Cisco switch is configured to have a static IP of 10.128.10.12, which is in VLAN 10, and a default gateway of 10.128.10.1.

How do I accomplish all of the following things:

1. Configure the port on the Meraki switch to be ***Trunk port using native VLAN 1***, and have the Cisco switch still work with a static IP in VLAN 10.

When I set the port on the Meraki switch to be ***Trunk port using native VLAN 1***, the Cisco switch loses connectivity because it's static IP is set to be 10.128.10.12.

The only way I am able to get in to the Cisco web interface is to set the Meraki switch port back to ***Trunk port using native VLAN 10***.

I would like to have the Meraki switch port to be ***Trunk port using native VLAN 1***, because all of the other Meraki switches I have are configured that way.

2. Configure a port on the Cisco switch to be an access port on VLAN 20.

Basically, what I need to be able to do is connect a device to a port on the Cisco switch, and have it be put into VLAN 20, so that in the Meraki interface, it shows both the switch (in VLAN 10), and the device (in VLAN 20).

I followed the instructions on [this page](http://sbkb.cisco.com/CiscoSB/GetArticle.aspx?docid=67844b99e2da4a7f88db0c588197487d_Creating_VLANs_on_Cisco_Managed_Switches.xml) to configure the port to be Tagged for VLAN 20, but it doesn't work - the device does not have network connectivity, and does not show up in the Meraki switch port client list.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Hey Ron, thanks for the follow-up! I am still working on getting the switch configured, and I will accept the answer once I've confirmed that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the general steps on the Cisco switch:

1. Define VLANs 10 and 20 on the switch
2. Configure the port connected to the Meraki as a Trunk port, with
   VLAN 1 as the native VLAN (should be the default).  Allow all VLANs
   on that port.
3. Configure the port connected to the device as an access port in VLAN
   20
4. Change the management VLAN on the switch to VLAN 10
5. For all devices downstream from the Cisco switch, decide which VLAN
   you want them to use, and configure their ports as access ports in
   the chosen VLAN.

Comment: 1. Done, 2. Done. 3. Done. 4. Having trouble with this one. First off, it seems you can't set the management VLAN port to be 10 unless there is a port set to VLAN 10 untagged with a computer connected. So I did that but now I can't access the switch management interface and am locked out - can't access the switch when the Meraki port is set to either VLAN 1 or 10, and can't even access the management interface or ping the switch from the computer connected to the port (although it's correctly picking up an IP in VLAN 10). About to factory reset the switch now so I can get back in.

Comment: You can get in via the console.

Comment: One step to add is to set the switch's default gateway to the router address for the management VLAN.